# Error while update object in generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

bellow error occurs when I want to update my Entity.
I was checking out all the objects . It seems everything is okay

```
public int Update(T entity)
{
    T data = _entities.Find(entity);
    _entities.Update(data);

    return context.SaveChanges();
}
```

System.ArgumentException: 'The key value at position 0 of the call to 
    'DbSet.Find' was of type 'Hazine', which does not match the 
     property type of 'string'.'

[image]but when I  want to update this error occurred

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/ef6/querying/): "The Find method on DbSet uses the primary key value". `entity` is surely no **key**.

Comment: I cant understand . are you say I should remove primary key from objects .because it exist

Comment: You surely need a foreign key on entity to get the references `data`-object. But you did not specifiy which attribute of `entity` should be used as foreign key.

Comment: I Have not any relationship but any T inherited from base class    so actually one tables created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send the primary key to the find method as a parameter.you can use:

```
Type t = entity.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("Id");
object id= prop.GetValue(entity);   
T data = _entities.Find(id);
```

You do not need to fetch the entity from the database. You can use the following code:

```
public int Update(T entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: and finally after it the update command is?It mean how to pass it end data

Comment: please checking a new post

Comment: oh yes . but _entities is missing in our rule. is it  violate something? because context responsible is only save changes

Comment: This is okay. However you can also use the following
`public int Update(T entity)
    {
     _entities.Update(entity);
     return context.SaveChanges();
    }`